Facing issue while integrating firebase testlab in my local mobile-automation project developed in webdriverIO with cucumber framwork
I am developing a mobile-automation project using webdriverIO & cucumber framework with Appium server. On localhost when we are launching multiple emulator in that case cpu got stuck & apps are crashing because of heavy load so i want to move running process to firebase testlab, i am new to firebase, can anyone let me know step-by-stpe process to integrate firebase testlab[cloud] in my local project [android studio] so i can write code locally & execute app-automation on firebase
it will be great help please
or any other way to meet this approach
i have tried till now by googling is:
created a new project in firebase testlab & downloaded google-services.json & followed step but tests are not running on firebase,
